# Fundamental difference in function value when fraction or decimal is used

Tags: functions

Excuse me for a basic question.
I was wondering why the function value is different:

[image]

This happens also when evaluating a function:

[image]

Obviously, the right answer is the second one, looking at the function. Why does this happen?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
Limit[(2 x - 1)/(Sqrt[2 x] - 1), x -> 0.5]
Limit[(2 x - 1)/(Sqrt[2 x] - 1), x -> 1/2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the individual pieces to see why.

The denominator

```
(Sqrt[2 x] - 1) /. x -> .5
(* 2.220446049250313*10^-16 *)
```

Close to zero for machine precision, but not exactly zero.

The numerator:

```
(2 x - 1) /. x -> .5
(* 0. *)
```

Closer to zero because `2 x` comes out to an integer, and we get zero divided by a non-zero value.

Increasing the precision can make the denominator essentially zero.

```
(Sqrt[2 x] - 1) /. x -> .5`20
(* 0.*10^-21 *)
```

which is why increasing the precision results in a (more) correct answer.

Comment: Increasing the precision isn't what fixes the problem. `Limit[(2 x - 1)/(Sqrt[2 x] - 1), x -> 0.5\`5]` (reduced precision!) yields `2.000`. The thing that matters is *controlling* the precision.

Comment: @JohnDoty That works in this case probably because specifying precision is forcing rounding off to an integer.  It make not work for the general case where integers are not involved.

Comment: It's not so much that it's an integer, but that the denominator is zero. Controlled precision is very good at inferring that an approximate result is consistent with zero. That, I suppose, causes `Limit` to actually compute a numerical limit rather than seeing `0./nonzero` at the limit point and taking that for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the documentation under "Possible Issues": "Limit may return an incorrect answer for an inexact input...".

`Limit` is a symbolic math function. In *Mathematica*, it is best to give symbolic machinery exact inputs. Presision loss can lead to incorrect answers.

If you must use inexact input, controlled precision may be useful:

```
Limit[(2 x - 1)/(Sqrt[2 x] - 1), x -> 0.5`20]
(* 2.000000000000000 *)
```

In controlled precision, *Mathematica*'s arithmetic tracks precision loss, and attempts to prevent it.

In answer to your edit,

```
Sqrt[2 x] - 1 /. x -> 0.5
(* 2.22045*10^-16 *)
```

So, the denominator isn't zero when the numerator is zero using machine arithmetic.

For more details of why this happens:

```
Trace[Sqrt[2 x] - 1 /. x -> 0.5]
```

You'll see it splits the square root calculation before converting the exact `Sqrt[2]` into an inexact machine number.

Comment: Thanks @John Doty. However, the same issue comes up also if I just evaluate a function. Will edit the orignial post.

Answer (score 3):

from the documentation on Limit

[image]